# can iOS class extracted from iOS binary?

Tags: ios, security, binary, reverse-engineering

Kindly let me know is there any possibility that iOS class can be extracted using reverse engineering process with utilities like class-dumpz on a jailbroken device? If it so,

1. Whether intruder can see the all the classes used to construct the    application?
2. Whether intruder can alter the logic of application by process    injection to modify in memory code?
3. Whether apple has provided any ways to secure the binary (i.e ipa or    app) ?

Please help us soon.

Comment: Kindly provide solution if you have

Answer (score 1):

Well I'll do my best to answer your question, but keep in mind that I've very little experience in reversing ipa applications.

> Whether intruder can see the all the classes used to construct the application?

Dumping a ipa is extremely easy on a jailbroken device. All you need is an ssh server installed on your device (and a small script to decrypt the executable if encrypted). Then you can use a software like IDA Pro or Hopper to disassemble the executable and have a look at the assembly code.

> Whether intruder can alter the logic of application by process injection to modify in memory code?

I don't know if is possible by process injection, but surely this is possible by patching the executable assembly code.

> Whether apple has provided any ways to secure the binary (i.e ipa or
>   app) ?

Yes, there is the FairPlay DRM for apps that are downloaded from the AppStore, but as I said earlier, there is a small script to decrypt it automatically.